# SQL Server: Select Top 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We just came across this in an old production stored proc (there is a lot more going on in here, but this is in one leg of its logic). Why would someone ever select top 0 rows from a table?  Is this some sort of SQL hack or trick I am not familiar with?

Comment: To get the column names/headers?

Comment: It definitely does that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To name columns in a UNION ALL

Be sure to read Alex K.'s answer as well. He has a lot of reasons that I have used as well. This was just the most obvious one.

Comment: I think this is likely the reason, just wanted to make sure there wasn't something else going on. Thanks.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, I'm pretty sure this was the reason for it in our case. Thanks!

Comment: I have used it in rare cases like when working with SSAS or other crazy situations.

Answer (score 58):

Its a way of getting an empty set; for example to create a new empty table with the same columns as an existing one;

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

Or to act a as source for column names
Or as a way to return column details but no data to a client layer
Or as a query to check connectivity

Its the same as;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0=1
```

Answer (score 3):

By doing this, you have an empty resultset with all columns instead of no result.
If the program using the stored procedure expects certain columns, it would crash otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this to grab the column names.

Comment: "just check if there was a match or not" -- Explain?

Comment: Nevermind, ignore that. :) I was thinking incorrectly. Been a while since I've used SQL Server and got confused. You called me out, sorry!

Comment: No problem, I wasn't calling you out... thought you knew something I didn't. This is why I posted the question! ;)

Comment: No harm, didn't mean it negatively.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create a temporary table where the collation of your DB and TEMPDB may differ.

```
SELECT TOP(0) column INTO #temp FROM [mytable]
```

Produces a temp table with same collation as my table. This then means

```
SELECT * FROM #temp T INNER JOIN [mytable] M ON M.column=T.column
```

Does not fail due to a collation error.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide an additional use:

If you want a message printed in the output rather than in messages, you could use

`select top 0 0 'Your message here'`

instead of

`print 'Your message here'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check if your SQL syntax is correct without loading any data.

Comment: A better solution to do that, would be to prepend `SET PARSEONLY ON` to the query. That way, you don't have to modify your query.

Answer (score -1):

I have mostly used it when creating temp tables from an existing DB table - without any data. The following is more reliable though than using top.

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 0;
```

Comment: This is not valid TSQL…