# Will "Where 0=1" parse full table or just return column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across this question:

[SQL Server: Select Top 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033957/sql-server-select-top-0)

I want to ask if I use the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0=1
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM table
```

will it return just the column names instantly, or will it keep on parsing the whole table and in the end return zero results?

I have a production table with 10,000 rows - will it check the `WHERE` condition on each row?

Comment: The SQL Server query optimizer is smart enough to see that `WHERE 0=1` can ***never ever*** be true and thus doesn't bother checking any rows - pointless....

Comment: what about other servers like oracle are they too smart ?

Comment: Most of them, if not all, probably are...

Comment: Similiar case. Create table with `CHECK` constraint like `col > 0` and try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 0`. If constraint is trusted then SQL Server engine won't touch rows. It is called *contradiction detection*.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The SQL Server query optimizer is smart enough to figure out that this `WHERE` condition can ***never ever*** produce a `true` result on any row, so it doesn't bother actually scanning the table.

If you look at the actual execution plan for such a query, it's easy to see that *nothing* is being done and the query returns immediately:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Marc_S, your image link is not working now. so please can you update it.

Comment: @Ajay2707 it is there. What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 15):

MySql is smart enough to detect it and know its impossible to do.

```
desc SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0=1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0=1
```

the `WHERE` clause never will be true so SQL Server is not going to scan all of your table.

And in the query

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM table
```

you are specifying `TOP 0` so SQL Server is very smart so it never scans your table for returning 0 rows.

Both the queries will return only the column headers.

Answer (score 2):

Both query is used for getting an empty set of table;

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM table
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0=1
```

As well as for achieve below things:

1. To get same structure of column name
2. Used for return column details but no data
3. And want query to check connectivity

Comment: yup , I am already using that for payload to a Search Widget while showing zero data but the column names, I was only worried about will it parse full table or not.

Comment: it just returns column name, so don't worry about use 0=1.